# Cannot install pinguy builder and found some errors package

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64. I will install Pinguy Builder, but i found some errors

I tried to install

```
sudo dpkg -i pinguybuilder_3.3-7_all.deb
```

and this is the output

```
(Reading database ... 167103 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack pinguybuilder_3.3-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking pinguybuilder (3.3-7) over (3.3-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pinguybuilder:
 pinguybuilder depends on squashfs-tools; however:
  Package squashfs-tools is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on casper; however:
  Package casper is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on libdebian-installer4; however:
  Package libdebian-installer4 is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on ubiquity-frontend-debconf; however:
  Package ubiquity-frontend-debconf is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on user-setup; however:
  Package user-setup is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on discover1 | discover; however:
  Package discover1 is not installed.
  Package discover is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on aufs-tools | unionfs-fuse; however:
  Package aufs-tools is not installed.
  Package unionfs-fuse is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on dpkg-dev; however:
  Package dpkg-dev is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not installed.
 pinguybuilder depends on python-glade2; however:
  P
dpkg: error processing package pinguybuilder (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pinguybuilder
```

i tried to update and install one of uninstalled package

```
apt-get update && apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

errors is constantly there

```
Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              

Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      

Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease             

Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                     
  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg             
  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://id.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg           
  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                           

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg              
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease 
W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'id.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pinguybuilder : Depends: casper but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libdebian-installer4 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: ubiquity-frontend-debconf but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: user-setup but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: discover1 but it is not installable or
                          discover but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: aufs-tools but it is not going to be installed or
                          unionfs-fuse
                 Depends: dpkg-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: gksu but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: python-vte but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: plymouth-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

what is occurring with those packages? why i can't install them? how can i install pinguy builder correctly?

Comment: are you connected to the internet?

Comment: yes, sure I am connected

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg` does not know about the repositories, and so cannot install the dependiencies.

To install the program and its dependincies, use `apt`:

```
sudo apt install ./pinguybuilder_3.3-7_all.deb
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/133794)

Comment: i did, but there is so many errors such E: Release 'pinguybuilder_3.3-7_all.deb' for 'libgnome-desktop-3-4' was not found

Comment: His problem is he can't connect to the repositories

Comment: yes, i think so. How the way i should to connect the repositories? updating system is also unused